# What might cause an Empty retrofit response?

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I have an API endpoint that is supposed to send a one-time password to a user email. I try it on postman and it works just fine. However it doesn't give any response in the code I am new to this, can anyone give me an answer. Here is my code...

```
// call to get OTP
public void makeApiCallForVerification(Context context, String email,String token){
    mApiServiceVerification = RetrofitInstance.getRetroClientWithToken(token).create(APIService.class);

    System.out.println("token is: " +token);
    mCallVerification = mApiServiceVerification.CheckUserVerification();
    
    mCallVerification.enqueue(new Callback<UserVerificationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserVerificationResponse> call, Response<UserVerificationResponse> response) {
            mLiveDataVerification.postValue(response.body());
            LiveDatauserVerificationStatus.postValue(response.code());


           if(response.body() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());

              SweetAlertDialog dialog=  new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                        dialog.setTitleText("Verification Sent to \n"+ email)
                        .setContentText("Check your Email Inbox")
                        .setNeutralButtonTextColor(Color.parseColor("#297545")).setCancelable(false);
                        dialog.show();
                try{

                    int OTP = response.body().getDataSentInEmail().getOtpNumber();
                    updateVerificationStatus( context,OTP,0);
                    OTPCodeLiveData.postValue(String.valueOf(OTP));
                    LiveDatauserVerificationStatus.postValue(0);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: err "+e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserVerificationResponse> call, Throwable t) {



            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
            System.out.println(call);
            LiveDatauserVerificationStatus.postValue(-1);
            ErrorLiveData.postValue(t.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + t.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

//on the Interface class

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("user/otp")
Call<UserVerificationResponse> CheckUserVerification();
```

Comment: Have you any error in Log?

Comment: Try adding an `OkhttpLoggingInterceptor` to your `OkhttpClient` so that you can see what the response you are getting looks like. From there you can debug further
https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: No errors currently

Answer (score 0):

Try changing APIService(interface) class like this("/" before user at @GET)

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("/user/otp")
Call<UserVerificationResponse> CheckUserVerification();
```

Comment: Retrofit forces you to add a `/` to the end of your base url so won't this simply result in the following `base_url//user/otp` ?

Comment: It's not necessary that retrofit will force you to add a  /  to the end of base url.
If you have added /  in base url then there's no need to add  /  in Interface (API Class)
But if not then you need to add / either in Interface(API Class) or Base URL

Comment: That's not true, at least in the version I am currently using (2.9.0). If you miss out the `/` it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /:` regardless of what you add to your endpoint definitions

Comment: I am using the latest version of retrofit that is 2.9.0 and i am using base url without `/` and it's working fine. I have added `/` in Interface and everything works perfect.
Maybe it depends on version/

Comment: yaa.. mine also can't accept the base URL without a / at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
```

Comment: I tried this and this is the log error I get:   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Can u test debug mode and first you shouldn't convert data, just check response.body(). Retrofit can able to show detail error message